# Issue with flow function in lodash

Tags: node.js, lodash

I started to work in a new project where I found lodash's `flow` function and I saw the uses of it here [docs](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flow) but in my project, in the following code, I found over there `flow([...])(state)` here what is `(state)` at the end of the function?

```
module.exports = (async function published(state) {
  return flow([
    setColumnIndex('my_pay_table', 1, 'rate_mode', getColumn('pay_structure', 'pay_per_id', state)),
    setColumnIndex('my_pay_table', 1, 'rate_amount', getColumn('pay_structure', 'pay_rate', state)),
    setColumnIndex('my_wo_title_table', 1, 'user_id', buildArtifact(ownerAlias, 'user', 'id', 1)),
    setColumnIndex('my_wo_title_table', 1, 'date_added', Date.now() / 1000),
  ])(state);
});
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Whatever it is when it’s passed in, assuming no side-effects in setColumnIndex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the lodash documentation, `flow` returns a function. In JavaScript it is possible to return functions without executing them.

We could refactor the code you provided to the following

```js
module.exports = (async function published(state) {
  // `func` here is a function
  const func = flow([
    setColumnIndex('my_pay_table', 1, 'rate_mode', getColumn('pay_structure', 'pay_per_id', state)),
    setColumnIndex('my_pay_table', 1, 'rate_amount', getColumn('pay_structure', 'pay_rate', state)),
    setColumnIndex('my_wo_title_table', 1, 'user_id', buildArtifact(ownerAlias, 'user', 'id', 1)),
    setColumnIndex('my_wo_title_table', 1, 'date_added', Date.now() / 1000),
  ]);
  // Here we execute that function with an argument `state`
  return func(state);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So far I found the solution. It actually uses Lodash's `curry` function.

```
let state = "Initial State";
const setColumnIndex = _.curry((table, index, column, value, state) => {
  if (typeof index !== 'number') {
    throw new Error(`Tried to setColumnIndex and specified a non-numeric index parameter (1): ${index}, did you mean to call setColumn?`);
  }
  return "New state"; // state = "Setting up new state here";
});

let result =_.flow([
    setColumnIndex('my_wo_table', 1, 'status_id', 2),
    setColumnIndex('my_wo_table', 1, 'label_id', 1),
    setColumnIndex('my_wo_table', 1, 'date_added', Date.now() / 1000),
])(state);

console.log(result); //=> "New state"
```

In the above code, if we notice that for `setColumnIndex` function has 5 parameters when we are calling from `flow` function, actually passing 4 parameters and with `(state)` in `curry` style total 5 parameters.